# Why was my edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, editing, review

I suggested an edit to a post and I don't see why it was rejected, can someone please explain?

https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/116594

The justification was

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

The OP said they wanted to avoid contrails and put in brackets "(chemtrails too)". [Chemtrails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemtrail_conspiracy_theory) are just a conspiracy theory about contrails, which the OP already said to avoid, so I removed the unnecessary repetition and irreverent reference to a conspiracy theory.

It didn't change the intent that the OP wanted to avoid audible or visual evidence of aircraft.

Answer (score 4):

I rejected your edit.

As some people are very serious about chemtrails, whether you or I believe in them makes no difference, OP had them mentioned, in a way that showed he wanted them in. It is not up to you, or me, to edit them out.
Chemtrails are not the same as contrails, so your editing did not take out a double word but a different thing.

It might be that they are not visible, if OP wants to be away from chemtrails, it is up to him to have it in the question.

Comment: The chemtrail conspiracy theory is generally along the lines of “the government put chems in the contrails, that’s why they sometimes don’t dissipate as quickly”. Even if they had chemicals in them, contrails is still the correct word (it’s an amalgamation of “condensation” and “trails”) and the fact that they are visible is precisely the issue. So I respectfully disagree that removing it changed the nature of the question. The point was the OP didn’t want to see or hear evidence of aviation, i.e. contrails, aircraft or noise.